# egalitarian PE allocation for public goods

Tags: public-economics

Suppose that there are 2 consumers, 1 private good($x$), 1 public good($y$) exists in this economy.
$u^i (x^i , y)=\gamma \ln y +\ln x^i$ and $e^i =\frac{E}{I}$ and $f(z)=z$ 
where $z$ is the input of private good to produce public good(that is, $y=f(z)$).

Find the egalitarian and competitive allocation.

And solutions are egalitarian's $x^i =\frac{E}{I(1+\gamma)}$, competitive's $x^i =\frac{E}{I+\gamma}$.
I can derive competitive's solution but how to derive egalitarian's $x^i$?